# Form of an element in $\langle\{asa^{-1}\,|\,a\in G, s\in S\}\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $S$ be a subset of a group $G$.

$\langle S\rangle$ denotes the smallest subgroup that contain S, i.e., $\langle S\rangle =\cap H$ where $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $S\subseteq H$.

My question is that for any element in $\langle\{asa^{-1}\,|\,s\in S, a\in G\}\rangle$, say $h$, can be express as $asa^{-1}$ or not. If so why?

Comment: Let us define $S^G = \{\, asa^{-1} \mid s \in S, a \in G \,\}$. Now, if every element of $\langle S^G \rangle$ *is* of the form $asa^{-1}$, then $\langle S^G \rangle = S^G $ itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For arbitrary subsets $S\subset G$, this is not true.

Here is a simple counterexample. Your subgroup must contain the identity $e$, but $asa^{-1}=e$ iff $s=e$, so if $S$ does not contain $e$, you won't be able to write every element of your subgroup as $asa^{-1}$ for $s\in S$.